# Java AES 128 ECB to AES 256 ECB conversion

Tags: java, cryptography, aes

I have an issue to upgrade an AES 128 bit encryption to AES 256 in ECB mode. But I'm unable to find any solution for that. Mostly solutions are there for AES 256 CBC mode. Any help is highly appreciated.

The exception that I got was due to bad padding

PS : I'm aware of the vulnerability of ECB mode in AES but this is what I need to implement at the moment.

```
import org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

public class Decrypt {
    public static String decryptPayload(String payload) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = {
                0x74, 0x68, 0x69, 0x73, 0x49, 0x73, 0x43, 0x53, 0x75, 0x63, 0x72, 0x65, 0x44, 0x4b, 0x55, 0x79
        };
        try {
            payload = payload.replace(' ', '+');
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(
                    Base64.decodeBase64(payload)));
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The implementation of AES 256 ECB I tried was as follows:

```
    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secretKey) {
        try
        {
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: what issue are you facing?

Comment: @njzk2 Updated the post with implementation that I tried for AES 256 ECB

Comment: good, but what is the result of that implementation? what exception do you get?

Comment: @njzk2 BadPaddingException is what I'm getting while decrypting using AES 256 ECB

Comment: how is it encoded / how are you sure the encoding is correct?

Comment: as an aside, `payload = payload.replace(' ', '+');` + `Base64.decodeBase64(payload)` is highly suspicious: base64 doesn't have spaces, so it could be that you're transforming the input the wrong way?

Comment: @njzk2 Okay, I see your point. Will make changes for that. But my question was how to incorporate the ```KeySpec``` parameter ? That part is not there in 128 bit implementation.

Comment: Your main question is "Java AES 128 ECB to AES 256 ECB conversion", for that you take your "decryptPayload" method and use the same 32 byte (256 bit) long key instead of a 16 byte (128 bit) long key that was used for encryption. All the stuff in "decrypt" method is for a key derivation using a password based key derivation (PBKDF2) functionality. To get your decryption to work you need to know how your encryption function looks like.

Comment: @MichaelFehr I'll try adding a 32byte key like you said and check.

Comment: @MichaelFehr It did work. Using a different implementation with a 32byte key. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

The entire solution which worked for me, thanks to @MichaelFehr

```
public void tester() {
        System.out.println("Program starts");
        String key = "5u7x!A%D*G-KaPdSgVkYp3s6v9y/B?E(";
        String payload = "Test string to test AES 256 ECB";
        String encrypted = "";
        String decrypted = "";
        // Encryption
        try{
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            final String encryptedString = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(payload.getBytes()));
            System.out.println("The encrypted string is\n"+encryptedString);
            encrypted = encryptedString;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // Decryption
        try
        {
            decrypted = encrypted.replace(' ', '+');
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            final String decryptedString = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted)));
            System.out.println("The decrypted string is\n"+decryptedString);
            decrypted=decryptedString;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should be able to accept your own answer by now. It won't get you any credit but it shows that your problem has been solved to others (so Michael, me and others can spend our time on other questions).

Comment: `key.getBytes()` A key should consist of random bytes, not a string. In that sense using PBKDF2 to derive a key from a password **is** the correct way to go. Basically you weakened the encryption protocol to avoid an implementation mistake here (but if you're still using ECB mode in 2021 to encrypt text, I guess you've already lost the battle; use the authenticated GCM mode instead). "tweakin'" it until it works is not a good idea when it comes to cryptography: the goal is to make it secure, not to make it work.